# The data structure of an associated token account's data field

Tags: spl-associated-token-account, account-data, ata

I used 'solana account --output json 'address'' to obtain the data field of a Token account, which is encoded in base64. I would like to know how it is structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the layout:

```
AccountLayout = struct<RawAccount>([
    publicKey('mint'),
    publicKey('owner'),
    u64('amount'),
    u32('delegateOption'),
    publicKey('delegate'),
    u8('state'),
    u32('isNativeOption'),
    u64('isNative'),
    u64('delegatedAmount'),
    u32('closeAuthorityOption'),
    publicKey('closeAuthority'),
]);
```

Lengths for these fields are: Public keys = 32 bytes, u64 = 8 bytes, u32 = 4 bytes and u8 = 1 bytes.

Meaning, after you decode the base64 representation of the account into byes, if you take the first 32 bytes, that will be the mint pubkey, the next 32 bytes are the owner pubkey, the next 8 bytes are the amount and so on.

You can use [unpackAccount()](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/unpackAccount.html) if you want to unpack an account in JS.